# получить количество товаров которые принадлежат к категории и n тасономиям

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Привет. Хочу получить количество товаров которые приналежат к категории с id = * и которые принадлежат к таксономиям с id .... (может быть несколько). Получать их обэкти не нужно так как будет очень много запросов из за чего будет большая нагрузка. Можна сделать через sql, а именно select count(*), но вот не могу составить запрос к базе, помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Категории товаров это и есть таксономии, только иерархические чаще всего, а теги - не еирархические. Вы можете обычным WP_Query выбрать все товары, указав в выборке из каких конкретно таксономий нужно брать эти товары

Comment: Вернее из каких конкретно термов определенной таксономии выбирать

Answer (score 1):

За основу можете взять пример выборки, как это реализовано у WooCommerce

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'add_product_count_view', 10);

    function add_product_count_view() {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID,'product_cat' );
    foreach( $terms as $term ) 
    {
        echo 'Product Category: '
            . $term->name
            . ' - Count: '
             . $term->count;

     }
    }
```

Здесь вы получаете кол-во товаров в каждой категории